# Pointer of pointers starts to go wild after being freed

Tags: c, pointers

I have a function that splits a string into multiple strings by certain char.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "tokens.h"

char isSeparator(char character, char *seps) {
    int i = 0;
    while(*(seps + i) != '\0') {
        if (*(seps + i) == character) {
            return 1;
        }
        ++i;
    }

    return 0;
    }

    int parse_tokens(char *str, char *seps, char ***tokens) {
        /* implemente aca la funcion parse_tokens */
        char **foundTokens = (char **) malloc(10*sizeof(char*));

    int i = 0; 
    int tokenCount = 0;
    int tokenLetter = 0;
    while(*(str + i) != '\0') {

        if (!isSeparator(*(str + i), seps)) {
            if(*(foundTokens + tokenCount) == NULL) {
                *(foundTokens + tokenCount)= (char *) malloc(30*sizeof(char));
            }
            *(*(foundTokens + tokenCount) + tokenLetter) = *(str + i);
            ++tokenLetter;
        } else {
            // Revisar si es que el slot de token actual no esta vacio
            if(*(foundTokens + tokenCount) != NULL) {
                ++tokenCount;
            }
            tokenLetter = 0;
        }    
        ++i;
    }
    if(*(foundTokens + tokenCount) != NULL) {
        ++tokenCount;
    }
    *(foundTokens + tokenCount + 1) = NULL;
    *tokens = foundTokens;
    return tokenCount;
}

void free_tokens(char **tokens) {
    /* implemente aca la funcion free_tokens */
    int i = 0;
    while(*(tokens + i) != NULL) {
        free(*(tokens + i));  
        ++i;   
    }
    free(tokens);
}
```

An example of use would be:

```
char **argv;
int argc= parse_tokens("hello,world", ",", &argv);
free_tokens(argv);
```

Using it like this:

```
{
    char **argv;
    int argc= parse_tokens("", " ", &argv);
}
{
    char **argv;
    int argc= parse_tokens("hello world", ",", &argv);
}
{
    char **argv;
    int argc= parse_tokens(
        "hola, como te va; bien?",
        " ,;",
        &argv);
}
```

Makes the last parse_tokens fail. Showing the first token as "como" instead of "hola".

The function works fine, but when I add free_tokens weird bugs start to appear. Some mallocs don't get called, previous token are found in a new allocated array, garabage data by the same program. Playing with the free function will yield different results.

Since this is for an assaingment the answers should contain the least code posible. In short the question is: May it be that calling free can change the values of subsequent function calls? And since it does, why would it? (The free function isn't showing any errors)

Comment: Show *all* of your code, including the code that calls `free()`. Also, show real code: the code you've given won't compile. (Is the variable `token` or `tokens`? What type is it and where is it declared?)

Comment: I'm voting to close, because there is no code shown to illustrate the problem in a reproducible fashion.

Comment: @AlexReynolds I added the least amount of code since it's an asingment. Added the required code to reproduce the issue

Comment: Doesn't the loop in the `free_tokens()` cry out to be written as: `for (int i = 0; tokens[i] != 0; i++) free(tokens[i]);` — that's certainly how I'd write it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The array of array tokens is ended by a `NULL` pointer. It could be written your way but with `tokens[i] != NULL` instead of 0

Comment: 0 is a perfectly good null pointer constant, but yes, you can also write NULL instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When run under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/), `valgrind` complains about:

```
==27284== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==27284==    at 0x40071C: parse_tokens (toks.c:37)
==27284==    by 0x400521: main (toks.c:79)
```

In the source code I'm using (reformatted so I can comprehend it), line 37 is:

```
 25 int parse_tokens(char *str, char *seps, char ***tokens)
 26 {
 27     /* implemente aca la funcion parse_tokens */
 28     char **foundTokens = (char **) malloc(10 * sizeof(char *));
 29 
 30     int i = 0;
 31     int tokenCount = 0;
 32     int tokenLetter = 0;
 33     while (*(str + i) != '\0')
 34     {
 35         if (!isSeparator(*(str + i), seps))
 36         {
 37             if (*(foundTokens + tokenCount) == NULL)
 38             {
 39                 *(foundTokens + tokenCount) = (char *) malloc(30 * sizeof(char));
 40             }
```

The trouble is that `malloc()` does not initialize the memory, so there is no way to know a priori whether `foundTokens[tokenCount]` will be NULL or not.

Changing the call to `malloc()` into `calloc(10, sizeof(char *))` eliminates that problem.

I added a loop to print the values from `parse_tokens()`, and still get one warning:

```
==27300== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==27300==    at 0x4E80F90: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1655)
==27300==    by 0x4F44830: __printf_chk (printf_chk.c:36)
==27300==    by 0x400596: main (stdio2.h:104)
==27300== 
0x51fc0d0 = [hello]
0x51fc130 = [world]
(nil) = [<null>]
==27300==
```

The `main()` function is:

```
int main(void)
{
    char **argv;
    int argc = parse_tokens("hello,world", ",", &argv);

    for (int i = 0; i <= argc; i++)
        printf("%p = [%s]\n", argv[i], (argv[i] != 0) ? argv[i] : "<null>");

    free_tokens(argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Since the close brace is line 86 in the source code, I'm a little puzzled as yet.

---

Got it; you are not null terminating the strings.  This code runs cleanly under `valgrind`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char isSeparator(char character, char *seps);
int parse_tokens(char *str, char *seps, char ***tokens);
void free_tokens(char **tokens);

char isSeparator(char character, char *seps)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (*(seps + i) != '\0')
    {
        if (*(seps + i) == character)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return 0;
}

int parse_tokens(char *str, char *seps, char ***tokens)
{
    char **foundTokens = (char **) calloc(10, sizeof(char *));
    int i = 0;
    int tokenCount = 0;
    int tokenLetter = 0;

    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (!isSeparator(str[i], seps))
        {
            if (foundTokens[tokenCount] == NULL)
                foundTokens[tokenCount] = (char *) malloc(30 * sizeof(char));
            foundTokens[tokenCount][tokenLetter] = str[i];
            ++tokenLetter;
        }
        else
        {
            if (foundTokens[tokenCount] != NULL)
            {
                foundTokens[tokenCount][tokenLetter] = '\0';
                ++tokenCount;
            }
            tokenLetter = 0;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    if (foundTokens[tokenCount] != NULL)
    {
        foundTokens[tokenCount][tokenLetter] = '\0';
        ++tokenCount;
    }
    foundTokens[tokenCount+1] = NULL;
    *tokens = foundTokens;
    return tokenCount;
}

void free_tokens(char **tokens)
{
    for (int i = 0; tokens[i] != NULL; i++)
        free(tokens[i]);
    free(tokens);
}

int main(void)
{
    char **argv;
    int argc = parse_tokens("hello,world", ",", &argv);

    printf("argc = %d\n", argc);
    for (int i = 0; i <= argc; i++)
        printf("%p = [%s]\n", (void *)argv[i], (argv[i] != 0) ? argv[i] : "<null>");

    free_tokens(argv);
    return 0;
}
```

For example:

```
==27349== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==27349== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==27349== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==27349== Command: ./toks2
==27349== 
argc = 2
0x51fc0d0 = [hello]
0x51fc130 = [world]
(nil) = [<null>]
==27349== 
==27349== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27349==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27349==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 140 bytes allocated
==27349== 
==27349== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==27349== 
==27349== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==27349== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Make sure you read initialized data all the time!  Do not rely on data from `malloc()` being zeroed; in general, it won't be.

---

This version of the code also compiles cleanly, but generally avoids subscripting operations whether written as `*(ptr + index)` or `ptr[index]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char isSeparator(char character, char *seps);
int parse_tokens(char *str, char *seps, char ***tokens);
void free_tokens(char **tokens);

char isSeparator(char character, char *seps)
{
    while (*seps != '\0')
    {
        if (*seps++ == character)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int parse_tokens(char *str, char *seps, char ***tokens)
{
    char **foundTokens = (char **) calloc(10, sizeof(char *));
    char **current = foundTokens;
    char *word = NULL;
    char c;

    while ((c = *str++) != '\0')
    {
        if (!isSeparator(c, seps))
        {
            if (word == NULL)
            {
                *current = (char *) malloc(30 * sizeof(char));
                word = *current++;
            }
            *word++ = c;
        }
        else
        {
            if (word != NULL)
                *word = '\0';
            word = NULL;
        }
    }
    if (word != NULL)
        *word = '\0';
    *tokens = foundTokens;
    return current - foundTokens;
}

void free_tokens(char **tokens)
{
    for (int i = 0; tokens[i] != NULL; i++)
        free(tokens[i]);
    free(tokens);
}

int main(void)
{
    char **argv;

    int argc = parse_tokens("hello,world", ",", &argv);

    printf("argc = %d\n", argc);
    for (int i = 0; i <= argc; i++)
        printf("%p = [%s]\n", (void *)argv[i], (argv[i] != 0) ? argv[i] : "<null>");

    free_tokens(argv);

    argc = parse_tokens(",abc,,axolotl,,zoological society gardens,,", ",", &argv);

    printf("argc = %d\n", argc);
    for (int i = 0; i <= argc; i++)
        printf("%p = [%s]\n", (void *)argv[i], (argv[i] != 0) ? argv[i] : "<null>");

    free_tokens(argv);

    return 0;
}
```

It has a second test, more stringent than the "hello,world" test, which it passes with a clean bill of health from `valgrind`.

Note that none of this code is secure against a string with more than 9 tokens in it, or with any token longer than 29 characters.  Fixing that requires more care handling lengths.

It would be possible to simply duplicate the source string and then split that with null bytes at the appropriate points.  This would simplify some aspects of the code (there'd be just two calls to `free()` in the code to free the tokens, for example).  It's safe; you won't ever need more space than that.  You also can't have more tokens than `(strlen(str) + 1)/2`, so a conservative (possibly wasteful) way to allocate the array of pointers would allocate `(strlen(str) + 3)/2` pointers up front.  You might well win back what you waste in the array of pointers from only allocating one chunk of memory to hold the tokens instead of one chunk per token.  You can always `realloc()` the array of pointers to the correct size before leaving the function if the discrepancy is big enough to warrant it.

---

#### Stress test

I've taken your stress test and run it against my final code.  It took too long to do ten million iterations, in part because the printing was scrolling (and I printed out the data after each invocation of `parse_tokens()` — in part because otherwise the `argc` used to capture the return value is unused otherwise, and my default compiling options complain about unused variables).  However, I cut the iterations down to 100,000 and redirected standard output to a file, and `valgrind` gave the code a clean bill of health (run time around 18s in the VM).

```
==27741== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==27741== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==27741== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==27741== Command: ./toks3
==27741== 
==27741== 
==27741== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27741==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27741==   total heap usage: 1,300,007 allocs, 1,300,007 frees, 59,000,310 bytes allocated
==27741== 
==27741== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==27741== 
==27741== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==27741== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)

real    0m18.166s
user    0m14.772s
sys 0m0.757s
```

I also put it into my first fully fixed version, piping the output to a file (so it was faster); still a clean bill of health.

```
==27751== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==27751== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==27751== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==27751== Command: ./toks2
==27751== 
==27751== 
==27751== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27751==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27751==   total heap usage: 1,300,007 allocs, 1,300,007 frees, 59,000,310 bytes allocated
==27751== 
==27751== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==27751== 
==27751== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==27751== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)

real    0m16.205s
user    0m15.576s
sys 0m0.527s
```

The test code (in place of the `main()` shown above) was:

```
static void print_args(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("argc = %d\n", argc);
    for (int i = 0; i <= argc; i++)
    {
        printf("%p = [%s]\n", (void *)argv[i],
               (argv[i] != 0) ? argv[i] : "<null>");
    }
}

static void test(void)
{
    {
        char **argv;
        int argc= parse_tokens("", " ", &argv); 
        print_args(argc, argv);
        free_tokens(argv);
    }
    {
        char **argv;
        int argc= parse_tokens("hello world", ",", &argv);
        print_args(argc, argv);
        free_tokens(argv);
    }
    {
        char **argv;
        int argc= parse_tokens("hola, como te va; bien?"," ,;",&argv); 
        print_args(argc, argv);
        free_tokens(argv);
    }
    {
        char **argv;
        int argc= parse_tokens("/bin:/usr/bin:/u/jperez",":",&argv);
        print_args(argc, argv);
        free_tokens(argv); 
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char **argv;

    int argc = parse_tokens("hello,world", ",", &argv);
    print_args(argc, argv);
    free_tokens(argv);

    argc = parse_tokens(",abc,,axolotl,,zoological society gardens,,", ",", &argv);
    print_args(argc, argv);
    free_tokens(argv);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)  
        test();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `*(foundTokens + tokenCount)= (char *) malloc(30*sizeof(char));` also did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Using `calloc()` in place of the other `malloc()` would also work.  Your code, even as fixed, is vulnerable to overflows if there are more than 9 tokens in the input, or if any of the tokens is longer than 29 characters.  Since you were using `*(ptr + index)` in many places, this is equivalent to but less readable than `ptr[index]`, so I replaced most occurrences of the one with the other.  OTOH, there are ways to write the code without continually adding the index — which is more idiomatic use of pointers in C.

Comment: `calloc` is not guaranteed to generate null pointers (they may use some representation other than all-bits-zero); for maximum correctness either loop and initialize each pointer, or structure the logic so it doesn't require such an initialization.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Point me to a current machine where `calloc()` does not yield null pointers?  If you're programming on an obscure mainframe, then there might be a problem, but you'd be aware of that.  Theoretically, you're correct.  In practice, it is not a real problem.  Certainly, it is not something to worry about until the main code is bullet-proof against long strings to tokenize, etc.